# Is there a sensible way of composing "non-instantaneous" functions?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, category-theory, differential-topology, vector-fields

If we try to implement a function $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ using real-world devices gadgets, there'll inevitably be a delay between changing the input values and seeing the desired change in the output value. We could try to model this using a first-order differential equation. Think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a smooth manifold $A$ and a $\mathbb{R}$ as a smooth manifold $B$. we want to define that a "non-instantaneous map" $f : A \rightarrow B$ is a way of assigning to each $a \in A$ a corresponding autonomous first-order differential equation $f(a)$ that moves us non-instantaneously toward the desired output value in $B$. We can formalize this as follows:

> **Definition.** Given smooth manifolds $A$ and $B$, a *non-instantaneous function* $A \rightarrow B$ is a smooth function $f:A \times B \rightarrow TB$, where $TB$ is the tangent bundle of $B$, such that for all $a \in A$, the function $f(a,-) : B \rightarrow TB$ is a section of the bundle projection $TB \rightarrow B$.

By currying $f$ into the form $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow TB),$ we see that this really just a clever way of assigning a vector field $f(a)$ to each $a \in A$, and since vector fields are basically first-order autonomous differential equations in disguise, this is a reasonable definition.

Now, I guess there's a reasonable way to compose such things, yielding a category. But honestly, I cannot see it. (In fact, I can't even see how to implement identity morphisms.)

> **Question.** Is there a sensible way of composing non-instantaneous functions as defined above? If not, what is the correct definition of non-instantaneous functions, such that composing them becomes possible and we get a category?

Comment: I think you'll be interested in reading about [delay-differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation).

Comment: @MichaelLee, thanks, that looks relevant.

Comment: Most DDE problems are hopelessly intractable, but you'd probably be most interested in starting with the ones with constant delay anyway.

Comment: If you instead use maps $A \to TB$ then you can compose using prolongation (this gives you the Kleisli category for the tangent space monad). But I don't know if this works for your intended semantics.

Comment: @DavidMyers, I think that's different. Though I note with interest the following (irrelevant, to my question) observation. Suppose that by a copointed endofunctor on a category $\mathbf{C}$ we mean an endofunctor $F$ together with a natural transformation $\varepsilon : F \rightarrow \mathrm{id}_\mathbf{C}$. Then the tangent functor can be viewed as a copointed endofunctor on $\mathbf{Man}^\infty$, the notion "pointed subset" yields a copointed endofunctor on $\mathbf{Set}$, and I suspect that "balls that remember their origin" yields a copointed endofunctor on the category of metric...

Comment: ....spaces. Furthermore, each copointed endofunctor $F$ has a corresponding notion of an $F$-digraph, which is defined as an object $X$ together with a morphsm $X \rightarrow FX$ whose composite with $\varepsilon_X : FX \rightarrow X$ is the identity on $X$. If we apply this to the notion "pointed subset" on $\mathbf{Set}$, we get the usual notion of a directed (simple) graph. If apply apply it to the tangent bundle, we get the notion of a manifold equipped with a vector field. And if we apply it the ball functor on the category of metric spaces...

Comment: ... , [we should get something interesting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395177/is-anyone-talking-about-ball-bundles-of-metric-spaces).